# android - best storage practice to show data in an activity

Tags: android, xml, templates, android-activity

I am looking to make an app that will display hundreds of text based pages with images, much like a website in many respects. I will either populate a template activity, or have the layout details within the plain text I store.

My question is, would it be better to store all the text parts in a DB, or in multiple XML files?

Also, if someone were rooted could they read both of them or is one more secure than the other?

Answer (score 1):

If a user is rooted he can access the db files, I have done it couple of times.
You can keep your resources inside the raw folder, and get them from there.

You can read more about resources here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Rooted users can't view the resources folder. What about if they get the split and unpack it? Aren't they supposed to basically be zip files?

Comment: There will be always a way to get that data.
Even when you use encryption, someone can always decrepit the data.